# Is it possible to use references to colors instead of colors in .xib files?

Tags: ios, macos, interface-builder, xib

When developing an iPhone app, I need to create a 'copy' of that app for various clients that, among other things, changes all the colors of the application's text, backgrounds, ...

I was wondering if it's possible to have the colors stored somewhere like:

- text -> #fffffff
- secondaryText -> #808080
- background -> #707070
- ...

And then use those referencees in the xib files instead of the actual color values. I want to do this in order to avoid duplicating xib files and making them impossible to maintain.
The idea would be something similar to android's resources where you can use '@color/text' for example

Comment: You can set colour values programmatically. I think IBOutlet helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give single app to three clients with different look and feel. But functionally they are same. Right?

Then you can have 3 xib files for the three clients
**mainView_first.xib, mainView_second.xib, mainView_third.xib**. Connect their outlets to a single .h file (mainView.h).
You can do your own customization in these xib files.
You can load a file like this

```
mainView *main=[[mainView alloc]initWithnibName:@"nameofthexibfile"];
```

Comment: Not exactly, I want to use the same xib file but instead of specifying a color directly, I want to tell the xib to go find the color in a plist, xml or whatever. Similar to what android does with a color.xml and "@color/dark-text"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this programatically -

a. create a color.plist file, in that store all the color names and values that you want to use.

b. Then create a color util class, which has the method to transform those values in `UIColor` object.

c. Use these methods through out your app to have background color, label color etc.

Comment: I'm doing this right now, but I thing it adds too much code that should be in the xib...